# Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out | Tableau

Tags: python, timeout, tableau-api

I'm trying to use Python to build a Hyper extract from a csv and publish it to my Tableau Server using the following code:

```
!pip install --upgrade tableau-api-lib
!pip install --upgrade tableauhyperapi
!pip install --upgrade panda

import pandas as pd

from tableau_api_lib import TableauServerConnection
from tableau_api_lib.utils.querying import get_projects_dataframe

from tableauhyperapi import HyperProcess, Connection, TableDefinition, SqlType, Telemetry, Inserter, CreateMode, TableName
from tableauhyperapi import escape_string_literal


TS_CONFIG = {
        'my_env': {
                'server': 'my_server',
                'api_version': '3.11',
                'username': 'my_username',
                'password': 'my_password',
                'site_name': 'my_site',
                'site_url': 'my_url'
        }
}

conn = TableauServerConnection(config_json=TS_CONFIG, env='my_env')
conn.sign_in()
```

However it yields the following error:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='myhost', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //api/3.11/serverinfo (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fdaafa0c910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
```

I'm aware of how the error occurs but I'm quite unsure of how to resolve or debug the error on Tableau. I have been following this [article](https://medium.com/snake-charmer-python-and-analytics/building-and-publishing-tableau-hyper-extracts-with-python-6ad096e7f3f3) for the task.

*Please Advise.*

*I will gladly help out with any additional information if required.*

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely an SSL certificate verification error which occurs when the browser cannot verify the SSL certificates returned by the server.

This can be solved by disabling SSL verification like this:

```
conn = TableauServerConnection(config_json=TS_CONFIG,  env='my_env', ssl_verify=False)
```